# jquery - get id attr of (this)

Tags: jquery-attributes

An anchor tag similar to this is clicked.

```
<a href="go.php?id=3aaa">Click Me</a>
```

`$(this)[0]` contains a string similar to `http://localhost/www/go.php?3aaa`

I wish to strip the "3" and "aaa" (values change according to what is clicked) into their own variables and test for their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var match = $(this)[0].match(/\?(\d{1,})(\w*)/);
```

then `match[1]` has the digit (3 like above) and `match[2]` has the string (aaa like above);

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly... but only if the path remains one level deep. How would you suggest amending the regex to handle unknown directory levels? (eg. http://localhost/www/newlevel/go.php?5bbb )  What is the regex for matching all chars after the question mark?

Comment: I tried it with the new link you gave and it still works, this regex matches number(s)+character(s) that are after a '?'. It doesnt care what is before the '?'.